# Chat that scrolls down when there is a new message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chat

I'm creating a web chat, but I have a problem: When they send messages, the chat doesn't scroll down. I think you should use JavaScript, but I'm not very experienced with it

This is the HTML code:

```html
    <div class="content-dx">
         <div id="messages"></div>
         <input type="text" id="messageBox" maxlength="100" placeholder="Type your Message here"/>
         <button id="send" onclick="Invio()"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
      </div>
```

"message" is the box that contains the chat, the messages that arrive

CSS code (if it can be useful, but I don't think):

```css
#messages{
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    height: 86%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    box-shadow: -1px 4px 28px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

What should I do to make the scroll automatically go down when there are messages?
I tried some codes, they work BUT when I want to go back to reread the messages, it won't let me go.

Comment: I solved! Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll to the bottom of the `messages` container with this code

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector("#messages").scrollHeight);
```

You need to tie this code to your `event` which controls received messages. *I couldn't write that part of the code because your question was missing the event section.*

Comment: Hi! i tried the code, but it doesn't work ... i don't know if i'm wrong an event, i put it in "content-dx", or should it go in "messages"? anyway it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @LSnake when your code received a new message from your chat application there is an even triggers. You should include this code in your `event`. Your `event` can be the `submit` event that `triggers` when you click the submit button or hit enter to submit your  message to the server. By looking at your code, you already have a submit handler `Invio()`

Comment: This way, putting the event in the submit, only works when I submit? I wish it would work every time someone sends a new message, however I tried it doesn't work the code: /

Comment: @LSnake You should have a `server` listening for submitted messages. This is usually done by using `socket.io` on the server side (your backend). Your backend should `emit` a received message `event` and that should trigger your scroll.

Comment: Yes, I used "emit", in fact it is strange that it does not work

Comment: what did i do wrong?

 <script>
       function Invio() {

window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector("#messages").scrollHeight);


       }

</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
function scrollToBottom(div) {
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight
}
const messages = document.querySelector("#messages")
scrollToBottom(messages)
```

Comment: iv'e tried ur code, i done something like this days ago, but it doesn't work bcause, i put the function of scroll into the div content-dx onchange=myfunc() <- this works good, but if i try to scroll manually my scrollbar she go down without sense, every time every seconds, im searching something that allow me to scroll down only when new message incoming into the messages box.

Comment: This code will simply scroll the div when the function is called.

Its up to you to call it whenever a new message comes in using whatever mechanism you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in javascript part:

```
const messageBox = document.querySelector("#messages");
messageBox.animate({scrollTop:messageBox.scrollHeight});
```

If this failed, then use this one:

```
const messageBox = document.querySelector("#messages");
messageBox.animate({scrollTop:messageBox[0].scrollHeight});
```

One of these will work. Check and give me the feedback whether it works or not.

Comment: As you question has some missing part. So you should put this code by yourself in the event function. When a new message comes/sent then this code will execute to go bottom of this message box automatically.

Comment: Can you tell me what event to put? and where , the code doesn't work

Comment: @LSnake Where you used this code? Listen, while sending a message you have to put this code into onsubmit event. I don't know what you have done inside your JavaScript code. So I can't clearly show you the place where you have to add this code.